# Got an unexpected dock

Tags: 20.04, lightdm, gdm, dock

I installed lightdm on my ubuntu 20.04 , and then I switched back to gdm3.
user login page is changed But the desktop environment is not changed yet , and I am facing many problems in it.
I am totally new user on ubuntu , can anyone help me ???

[image]

This is the image of my desktop

Comment: As a new user, you did a lot of customizations. Undo them first. Actually, you seem to run the Unity desktop environment, which is not (anymore) the default desktop environment. Log out, then before logging in, click the cog wheel and select Ubuntu desktop to login in to the default desktop.

Comment: please clearly list out the changes you have made